# How to get list item from a different site collection using javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

I have two site collection like site1 and site2. I am working in site1 application and I want to get a list item from site2.

This is the code I am using:

```
var ctx;   
var listItem;
var title;
var col1;
var col2;

function SetItemValue(listItemId, listId, siteUrl, webUrl) {
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web;
    var site = ctx.get_site(siteUrl);//Here passing the second sitecollection url     

    if (webUrl != undefined && webUrl != '')
        web = site.openWeb(webUrl);
    else
        web = site.openWeb('');

    var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);//Here passing the valid guid of list id
    listItem = list.getItemById(listItemId);
    ctx.load(list);
    ctx.load(listItem);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(OnListLoaded);

    list.update();
    web.update();
    ctx.load(web);
}

function OnListLoaded() {
    listItem.set_item(col1, 'Hi');
    listItem.set_item(col2, 'Test');
    listItem.update();

    ctx.load(listItem);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(OnListUpdated, OnError);
}

function OnListUpdated(args) {
}

function OnError(sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_message());
}
```

It will throw a message like "List does not exist". I think it will check the list from first site collection and  that's why this message will popup.

Could any one tell me how to get list item from a different site collection using javascript?

Comment: See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23209/sharepoint-2010-javascript-client-object-model-cross-site-collections

Answer (score 5):

There are several confusing things in your code. I suppose it is somewhat testing code, but anyway, I'd like to mention some of the mistakes:

- There is no need for loading anything into the context (with `ctx.load(...)`) since you're trying just to update an item. Loading into context is supposed for retrieving information from the server side to the client side, for further usage (displaying, analysing, etc.). And all you're going to do here, apparently, is to update the item in either case, no matter what is it's current state.
- You are not supposed to place any code after the `ctx.executeQueryAsync(OnListLoaded);` statement, you should place it into the `OnListLoaded` function instead. Otherwise, you could get some misleading errors.
- OnError function should be passed as a second parameter to `ctx.executeQueryAsync` method, if you want to get any error message from the server side.

There are also some other things, so I would say, that the code is anxiously cluttered and probably this is the first problem with it.

After all these mistakes and inaccuracies, it was not a surprise to hit upon the misusage of the [ctx.get_site() property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553781.aspx). It doesn't allow any arguments. Actually, it is a property getter, not a method :)

Instead, for getting particular site collection, there is [SP.ClientContext constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658863.aspx).

So, the code should look something like this:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/site2';
var listId = '...'; // the list guid here
var listItemId = 1;

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);
var listItem = list.getItemById(listItemId);
listItem.set_item('Title', 'new title');
listItem.update();
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() { alert('all ok!'); },
    function(sender, args) { alert('ERROR! ' + args.get_message()); });
```

Unfortunately, this code **will not work**.

If you will try to run it, you will get the following error:

> The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your
>   Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

Based on my knowledge, there is no acceptable way to work it around using ECMAScript Client Object Model. You can check out [this related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23209/sharepoint-2010-javascript-client-object-model-cross-site-collections) for details.

However, there are some other options:

1. You can use SharePoint web service Lists.asmx and its [UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx) method.
2. You can use server callback and do the work server-side.

**Update:**

The sample code for updating an item using Lists.asmx (jquery should be included):

```
// helper function for calling the Lists.asmx web service
function batchUpdate(siteUrl, listId, batch)
{
    var soapEnv =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '+
            'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" '+
            'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> '+
          '<soap:Body>'+
            '<UpdateListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">'+
              '<listName>' + listId + '</listName>'+
              '<updates>' + batch + '</updates>'+
            '</UpdateListItems>'+
          '</soap:Body>'+
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems");
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: function (xData, status) { alert(status); },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    });
}


var listItemId = 1;
var title = 'new title';
var listId = '{PUT-YOUR-GUID-HERE}';
var siteUrl = 'http://localhost/sites/site2';
var batch =
        '<Batch OnError="Continue">'+
            '<Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">'+
                '<Field Name="ID">' + listItemId + '</Field>'+
                '<Field Name="Title">' + title + '</Field>'+
            '</Method>'+
        '</Batch>';

batchUpdate(siteUrl, listId, batch);
```

I've tested this code and it works.

Comment: +1000. The solution, as @MikeOryszak alludes to in his answer in that other question, is that you can call UpdateListItems (or one of the other sharepoint web services) using plain 'ole AJAX.

Comment: Hi Omlin, Thanks for your reply, it's very useful for me and could you please tell me how to access the server side code from client side

Comment: @Rasu, you can use either ASP.Net callback techniques or the jquery ajax extension for this purpose. However, I'd recommend to call to Lists.asmx, because this approach seems much easier and more appropriate for your particular task. You can find the example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/10/creating-list-items-with-jquery-and-the-sharepoint-web-services.aspx

Comment: Hi Omlin, i am really sorry to say this, i can't understand this article, i want to update the list item, could you provide the sample code please.

Comment: @Rasu, ok, I've updated the answer with the working code. Although, I'd recommend you to read intently the MSDN topic about the UpdateListItems (the link was provided in the answer), and google all the things which you don't understand, because without a basic knowledge about what you're doing, you will most likely struggle with elementary problems forever...

Comment: @Rasu, you're welcome. Please, don't forget to accept the answer (click the check mark under the answer's rating), to point other visitors that it is correct and that the problem was solved.